# how to test django model form?

Tags: django

i wrote a test case:

```
class MyTestCreateFilter(TestCase):

    def test_createfilter(self):
        test_filter = Filter(user_profile_id= 3,
        keyword = 'ca',
        industry = 'it',
        zip_code = '50002',
        distance = 30,
        creation_date = datetime.date.today(),
        last_run_date = datetime.date.today()
        )


        test_filter_form = FilterForm(instance=test_filter)

        self.assertEqual(test_filter_form.is_valid(), False)#without data
        test_filter_form = FilterForm({'user_profile_id':3,'keyword': 'ca','industry':'it','zip_code':'50002','distance':30,'creation_date': datetime.date.today(),
        'last_run_date': datetime.date.today() }, instance=test_filter)
        print test_filter_form.is_valid()
```

giving the error:

```
DoesNotExist: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

---

this is my form.how to write test case:

class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:

    model=Filter

    exclude=('user_profile','creation_date','last_run_date')

    widgets = {
        'zip_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "e.g.                     20708"}),
    }

def clean(self):

    user_profile = self.instance.user_profile

    keyword = self.cleaned_data.get("keyword")
    if Filter.objects.filter(user_profile=user_profile, keyword=keyword).exclude(id=self.instance.id).count() > 0:
        msg = u"A filter with that keyword already exists!"
        self._errors["keyword"] = self.error_class([msg])

    return self.cleaned_data
```

when i test the form giving this error:

user_profile = self.instance.user_profile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 343, in **get**

```
raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist
```

DoesNotExist

how to solve it?

Comment: It might be useful to [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31046998/edit) the model to your question. As well as the full backtrace.

Comment: no.it is not worked for  me.giving same error

Answer (score 0):

Simply creating model object will not create the record in the database.

Use `.objects.create` to create a record.

```
test_filter = Filter.objects.create(
    user_profile_id= 3,
    keyword = 'ca',
    industry = 'it',
    zip_code = '50002',
    distance = 30,
    creation_date = datetime.date.today(),
    last_run_date = datetime.date.today()
)
```

or use `save`:

```
test_filter = Filter(...)
test_filter.save()
```