# how to test model form in django?

Tags: python, django

wrote a test case to test the *FilterForm*

```
class MyTestCreateFilter(TestCase):

  def test_createfilter(self):
    self.client = Client()     
    self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='bizi111',email='test5@example.com',password='bizi111')
    self.user = authenticate(username='bizi111', password='bizi111')
    #print self.user
    self.factory = RequestFactory()
    request = self.factory.get('/filter/new')
    request.user = self.user
    response = create_or_edit_filter(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    filterform = FilterForm()
    #print filterform.is_valid()
    form_data = {'keyword': 'it','industry':'it','zip_code':'50005','distance':30}

    filteform = FilterForm(form_data)

    self.assertEqual(filteform.is_valid(), True)
```

**FilterForm has a clean method:**

```
    def clean(self):
        #print self.instance.user_profile
        user_profile = self.instance.user_profile
        keyword = self.cleaned_data.get("keyword")
        if Filter.objects.filter(user_profile=user_profile, keyword=keyword).exclude(id=self.instance.id).count() > 0:
            msg = u"A filter with that keyword already exists!"
            self._errors["keyword"] = self.error_class([msg])

        return self.cleaned_data
```

**giving this error:**

> File "/home/suma/workspace2/bizintro/bizintro/forms.py", line 80, in
>   clean
>       user_profile = self.instance.user_profile   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py",
>   line 343, in **get**
>       raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist DoesNotExist

how to solve it.

Comment: What don't you understand? The error message is pretty explicit: the user in `self.instance` does not have a `user_profile` yet you're trying to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to test django model form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046998/how-to-test-django-model-form)

Answer (score 3):

Your Form appears to be a Bound form, which means it is supposed to have an instance of some model attached to it. And it doesn't.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#bound-and-unbound-form-instances

Since I don't know what kind of model this is supposed to be, I cant tell you much but you should add something that looks like:

```
filterform = FilterForm()
#print filterform.is_valid()
form_data = {'keyword': 'it','industry':'it','zip_code':'50005','distance':30}

filterform = FilterForm(form_data)

filterform.instance = # Some object here...


self.assertEqual(filterform.is_valid(), True)
```